# How do I change the line thickness in a table using python docx

Tags: python, ms-word, python-docx

[Line thickness 1 within a table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4K2Z.png)

[Line thickness 2 within a table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEhrX.png)

I am currently trying to change the line thicknesss of a table within a Microsoft word document. The table comes with a default line thickness of 1 pt, I am trying to find a way to change the line thickness to 2pt using python docx.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

documentation for setting table/cell border is available here: http://officeopenxml.com/WPtableBorders.php

i've reused the existing code available to set table cell border answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/49615968/5736491 and modified it to set single table property. this will set the uniform property for all borders within the table, and it is stored at the table level (instead of at the individual cell level):

```
from docx.oxml import OxmlElement
from docx.oxml.ns import qn
from docx.table import Table
from docx import Document

def set_table_border(table: Table, **kwargs):
    """
    Sets table border
    Usage:

    set_table_border(
        table,
        top={"sz": 12, "val": "single", "color": "#FF0000", "space": "0"},
        bottom={"sz": 12, "color": "#00FF00", "val": "single"},
        start={"sz": 24, "val": "dashed", "shadow": "true"},
        end={"sz": 12, "val": "dashed"},
    )
    """
    tbl  = table._tbl
    tblPr = tbl.tblPr

    # check for tag existnace, if none found, then create one
    tblBorders = tblPr.first_child_found_in("w:tblBorders")
    if tblBorders is None:
        tblBorders = OxmlElement('w:tblBorders')
        tblPr.append(tblBorders)

    # list over all available tags
    for edge in ('start', 'top', 'end', 'bottom', 'insideH', 'insideV'):
        edge_data = kwargs.get(edge)
        if edge_data:
            tag = 'w:{}'.format(edge)

            # check for tag existnace, if none found, then create one
            element = tblBorders.find(qn(tag))
            if element is None:
                element = OxmlElement(tag)
                tblBorders.append(element)

            # looks like order of attributes is important
            for key in ["sz", "val", "color", "space", "shadow"]:
                if key in edge_data:
                    element.set(qn('w:{}'.format(key)), str(edge_data[key]))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    doc = Document()
    t = doc.add_table(rows=1, cols=3)

    border_prop = {
        'sz': '16', # table border thickness (8=1pt => 16 = 2pt)
        'val': 'single', # line style
        'color': 'auto' # border color
    }
    set_table_border(t, top=border_prop, bottom=border_prop,
                        end=border_prop, start=border_prop,
                        insideH=border_prop, insideV=border_prop)

    doc.save('borders.docx')
```